# Can I fill big cracks with this product

Tags: walls

[image]I have a big crack in my wall. Don't have a photo but looks like the image below.  Its about 5 times 3 inches and deep you can see the bricks behind.

I want to use this product to fill it as it is allergy friendly  https://auropaint.co.uk/product/natural-wall-filler-no-329/

However correct me if im wrong but I think you need to use a spray to fill these big holes rather than a paste?
If I can use the product how shoudl I go about filling it?  Should I try to put some card behind the wall then paste over it, can I just apply some paste at the bottom and build up?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a hole not a crack.

Comment: Search for "deep hole filler". Follow the instructions: if it says you will need to fill it to only some thickness at a time and repeat, do that.

Comment: Can't I use the product above even if it is a deep hole filler?  I really want to as it is allergy and voc friendly.

Comment: You can try - be prepared to do it correct if it does not work.

Comment: If you really want to, then do it. You know the product you'd like to use and you have the hole, which we can't see.  If it works, fine, if not, then you'll be in the same boat as most of us have been in at one time or another.